# SwitfUI: access the specific scene's ViewModel on macOS

Tags: macos, mvvm, swiftui

In this simple example app, I have the following requirements:

1. have multiple windows, each having it's own `ViewModel`
2. toggling the `Toggle` in one window should *not* update the other window's
3. I want to also be able to toggle via menu

[image]

As it is right now, the first two points are *not* given, the last point works though. I do already know that when I move the `ViewModel`'s single source of truth to the `ContentView` works for the first two points, but then I wouldn't have access at the `WindowGroup` level, where I inject the commands.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ViewModelAndCommandsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ContentScene()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var toggleState = true
}

struct ContentScene: Scene {
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()// injecting here fulfills the last point only…
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(vm)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
        .commands {
            ContentCommands(vm: vm)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentCommands: Commands {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(before: .toolbar) {
            Button("Toggle Some State") {
                vm.toggleState.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel//injecting here will result in window independant ViewModels, but make them unavailable in `ContactScene` and `ContentCommands`…
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $vm.toggleState, label: {
            Text("Some State")
        })
    }
}
```

How can I fulfill theses requirements–is there a SwiftUI solution to this or will I have to implement a `SceneDelegate` (is this the solution anyway?)?

#### Edit:

To be more specific: I'd like to know how I can go about instantiating a ViewModel for each individual scene and **also** be able to know from the menu bar which ViewModel is meant to be changed.

Comment: Maybe try to find out what the "old" way of adding items to the Menu. Then adding them in `ToggleView`.

Comment: Fair point. That would mean, I'd have to bridge to use an AppDelegate and instantiate my menu in `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` I guess–which would also mean that pure SwiftUI lifecycle will not work for this right now...

Comment: Having looked into this further, I still can't seem to figure out how to get a handle on the currently active window and its viewmodel. I've come to the conclusion that that's what I would need to differentiate the target viewmodel in my "Toggle Some State" button...

Comment: I agree. Look at my answer below. Instead of a `ViewModel` look at the `View` as a `DetailView` where the toggle is a part of a `Model` that can be used anywhere. vs only being targeted to a single view. The "source of truth" has to be in a single location where you can fetch/retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, see the code below. The project is called `WindowSample` this needs to match your app name in the URL registration.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WindowSampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ContentScene()
    }
}
//This can be done several different ways. You just
//need somewhere to store multiple copies of the VM
class AStoragePlace {
    private static var viewModels: [ViewModel] = []
    
    static func getAViewModel(id: String?) -> ViewModel? {
        var result: ViewModel? = nil
        if id != nil{
            result = viewModels.filter({$0.id == id}).first
            
            if result == nil{
                let newVm = ViewModel(id: id!)
                viewModels.append(newVm)
                result = newVm
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

struct ContentCommands: Commands {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(before: .toolbar) {
            Button("Toggle Some State \(vm.id)") {
                vm.testMenu()
            }
        }
    }
}
class ViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    @Published var toggleState = true
    
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }
    func testMenu() {
        toggleState.toggle()
    }
}
struct ContentScene: Scene {
    var body: some Scene {
        //Trying to init from 1 windowGroup only makes a copy not a new scene
        WindowGroup("1") {
            ToggleView(vm: AStoragePlace.getAViewModel(id: "1")!)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
        .commands {
            ContentCommands(vm: AStoragePlace.getAViewModel(id: "1")!)
        }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "1"))
        //To open this go to File>New>New 2 Window
        WindowGroup("2") {
            ToggleView(vm: AStoragePlace.getAViewModel(id: "2")!)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
        .commands {
            ContentCommands(vm: AStoragePlace.getAViewModel(id: "2")!)
        }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "2"))
        
        
    }
}
struct ToggleView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Makes copies of the window/scene
            Button("new-window-of type \(vm.id)", action: {
                //appname needs to be a registered url in info.plist
                //Info Property List>Url types>url scheme>item 0 == appname
                //Info Property List>Url types>url identifier == appname
                if let url = URL(string: "WindowSample://\(vm.id)") {
                    openURL(url)
                }
            })
            
            //Toggle the state
            Toggle(isOn: $vm.toggleState, label: {
                Text("Some State \(vm.id)")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I appreciate it. After spending (another) 2 h, I still can't make head or tails out of it. While the sample code above is a really very basic example showing the issue at hand, my real app I'd have to use this for is an app that calls an api with a customised query, that can be different for each window. So, naturally, this query might be different for each window. I also want to be able to reload via menu and Cmd+R , which is what I'd need the active window for. Right now, there doesn't seem to be a _simple_ way to achieve this, so I guess I am giving in for now. :-(

Comment: See the new code. I think it might work. It just fell right into a project that I am working on.

Comment: It's so close, and maybe having two separate windows will do for the time being. What bugs me is that it's not dynamic. Would be perfect if `File`>`New Window` would just instantiate a new `ViewModel` with a new `UUID` for this specific new Window/Scene. I just cannot figure out where this `UUID` should be created. Will have to play around some more to perhaps find a way... _But_ it's much closer than ever before and I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I'll keep thinking but I don't think that is possible. Because the menu bar doesn't seem to be dynamic I found a few references where that mentioned that the `menuBuilder` runs at the very start. To be able to affect the toggle it has to be there from the very start. I haven't looked too much into it. But, `DocumentGroup` creates documents upon `init`, that is what allows them to have a menu bar for specific documents. Which seems to be what you are trying to do similar what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, the "only" thing I'd need would be a handle to the currently active window and its `ViewModel` at the `Button` level I guess. Perhaps looking into `DocumentGroup` might be a next step...