# Menu Command Buttons don't disable in reaction to Published variable changes

Tags: macos, swiftui

**Situation:**
I need the menu bar to recognise the active tab in a TabView, even when multiple windows are open. I have found this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334001/2682035), which seems to work in principal, but not in practice.

**Problem:**
Menu bar buttons do not disable immediately when their corresponding tab is changed. However, they will disable correctly if another State variable is modified.

**Minimal example which now works:**
I made this without the code for managing multiple windows because the problem seemed to occur without that. Thanks to the suggestion from **lorem ipsum**, this will now function as expected.

```
import SwiftUI

enum TabType: String, Codable{
    case tab1 = "first tab"
    case tab2 = "second tab"
}

public class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activeTab: TabType = .tab1
}

struct MenuCommands: Commands {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel // CHANGED
    @Binding var someInformation: String
    
    var body: some Commands{
        CommandMenu("My menu"){
            Text(someInformation)
            Button("Go to tab 1"){
                viewModel.activeTab = .tab1
            }
            .disabled(viewModel.activeTab == .tab1) // this now works as expected
            Button("Go to tab 2"){
                viewModel.activeTab = .tab2
            }
            .disabled(viewModel.activeTab == .tab2) // this does too
            Button("Print active tab"){
                print(viewModel.activeTab) // this does too
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Tab: View{
    var tabText: String
    @Binding var someInformation: String
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Inside tab " + tabText)
            TextField("Info", text: $someInformation)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @Binding var someInformation: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $viewModel.activeTab){
            Tab(tabText: "1", someInformation: $someInformation)
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "circle")
                }
                .tag(TabType.tab1)
            Tab(tabText: "2", someInformation: $someInformation)
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Tab 2", systemImage: "circle")
                }
                .tag(TabType.tab2)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct DisableMenuButtonsMultiWindowApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() // CHANGED
    @State var someInformation: String = ""
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(someInformation: $someInformation)
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
        .commands{MenuCommands(viewModel: viewModel, someInformation: $someInformation)}
    }
}
```

**Slightly less minimal example that doesn't work:**

Unfortunately that didn't work in my app, so here is a new minimal example that works closer to the actual app and will observe multiple windows, except it has the same issue as before.

```
import SwiftUI

enum TabType: String, Codable{
    case tab1 = "first tab"
    case tab2 = "second tab"
}

public class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activeTab: TabType = .tab1
}

struct MenuCommands: Commands {
    @ObservedObject var globalViewModel: GlobalViewModel
    @Binding var someInformation: String
    
    var body: some Commands{
        CommandMenu("My menu"){
            Text(someInformation)
            Button("Go to tab 1"){
                globalViewModel.activeViewModel?.activeTab = .tab1
            }
            .disabled(globalViewModel.activeViewModel?.activeTab == .tab1) // this will not disable when activeTab changes, but it will when someInformation changes
            Button("Go to tab 2"){
                globalViewModel.activeViewModel?.activeTab = .tab2
            }
            .disabled(globalViewModel.activeViewModel?.activeTab == .tab2) // this will not disable when activeTab changes, but it will when someInformation changes
            Button("Print active tab"){
                print(globalViewModel.activeViewModel?.activeTab ?? "") // this always returns correctly
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Tab: View{
    var tabText: String
    @Binding var someInformation: String
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Inside tab " + tabText)
            TextField("Info", text: $someInformation)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var globalViewModel : GlobalViewModel
    @Binding var someInformation: String
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel  = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HostingWindowFinder { window in
          if let window = window {
            self.globalViewModel.addWindow(window: window)
            print("New Window", window.windowNumber)
            self.globalViewModel.addViewModel(self.viewModel, forWindowNumber: window.windowNumber)
          }
        }
        
        TabView(selection: $viewModel.activeTab){
            Tab(tabText: "1", someInformation: $someInformation)
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "circle")
                }
                .tag(TabType.tab1)
            Tab(tabText: "2", someInformation: $someInformation)
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Tab 2", systemImage: "circle")
                }
                .tag(TabType.tab2)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct DisableMenuButtonsMultiWindowApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var globalViewModel = GlobalViewModel()
    @State var someInformation: String = ""
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(someInformation: $someInformation)
                .environmentObject(globalViewModel)
        }
        .commands{MenuCommands(globalViewModel: globalViewModel, someInformation: $someInformation)}
    }
}

// everything below is from other solution for observing multiple windows

class GlobalViewModel : NSObject, ObservableObject {
  
  // all currently opened windows
  @Published var windows = Set<NSWindow>()
  
  // all view models that belong to currently opened windows
  @Published var viewModels : [Int:ViewModel] = [:]
  
  // currently active aka selected aka key window
  @Published var activeWindow: NSWindow?
  
  // currently active view model for the active window
    @Published var activeViewModel: ViewModel?
  
  override init() {
    super.init()
    // deallocate a window when it is closed
    // thanks for this Maciej Kupczak 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(onWillCloseWindowNotification(_:)),
      name: NSWindow.willCloseNotification,
      object: nil
    )
  }
  
  @objc func onWillCloseWindowNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let window = notification.object as? NSWindow else {
      return
    }
    var viewModels = self.viewModels
    viewModels.removeValue(forKey: window.windowNumber)
    self.viewModels = viewModels
  }
  
  func addWindow(window: NSWindow) {
    window.delegate = self
    windows.insert(window)
  }
  
  // associates a window number with a view model
  func addViewModel(_ viewModel: ViewModel, forWindowNumber windowNumber: Int) {
    viewModels[windowNumber] = viewModel
  }
}

extension GlobalViewModel : NSWindowDelegate {
  func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
      windows.remove(window)
      viewModels.removeValue(forKey: window.windowNumber)
      print("Open Windows", windows)
      print("Open Models", viewModels)
      // windows = windows.filter { $0.windowNumber != window.windowNumber }
    }
  }
  func windowDidBecomeKey(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
      print("Activating Window", window.windowNumber)
      activeWindow = window
      activeViewModel = viewModels[window.windowNumber]
    }
  }
}

struct HostingWindowFinder: NSViewRepresentable {
  var callback: (NSWindow?) -> ()
  
  func makeNSView(context: Self.Context) -> NSView {
    let view = NSView()
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak view] in
      self.callback(view?.window)
    }
    return view
  }
  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

**What I've tried:**
Changing viewModel to Binding, StateObject **and now changing to StateObject and Observed Object**. It also doesn't matter if it's sent to the ContentView as a Binding or EnvironmentObject, it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DisableMenuButtonsMultiWindowApp` change

```
@State var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

To

```
@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
```

And in the `MenuCommands` use

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
```

instead

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

`@State` is used to initialize value types such as a `struct` and `@StateObject` is for reference type `ObservableObject`s such as your `ViewModel`.

Something else to note is that each `@State` does not know about changes to another `@State` an `@Binding` is a two-way connection.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm always getting the difference between those mixed up. That worked in the minimal example. Unfortunately, when I went to go try it in my actual app, it didn't work. Therefore I've supplied a new (slightly less) minimal example.

Comment: @jaimepapier then that would be a different question but the issue is that you are Chaining ObervableObservable objects. The dictionary of view models does not work as you expect. If I answered your original question please accept the answer with the green check mark.

Comment: It's alright, I got it working. I just changed `        .commands{MenuCommands(globalViewModel: globalViewModel, someInformation: $someInformation)}
`  to `.commands{MenuCommands(activeViewModel: globalViewModel.activeViewModel ?? ViewModel(), someInformation: $someInformation)}` and then used activeViewModle instead of the global version in the command line. I tried that before but it didn't work because I hadn't set up the ObservableObjects correctly (as you said). Thanks again!