# How to have scene-specific state in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I'm creating a macOS application that allows you to have multiple windows open. Each one of those windows (or scenes) need their own state, as the document/text/other states of that window are bound to it.

I also want to get that state in the `.commands` modifier so I can use the state to add keybindings.

**The following I tried does not quite work, as all the state is global across all open windows (i.e. keybindings and text affect all instances of the application, while they must be different):**

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct QCCApp: App {

    @StateObject var compiler = UIStateController()

    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: QCCDocument()) { file in
            ContentView()
                // A function I've written that combines the file into state
                .environmentObject(compiler.attachDocument(file))
        }
        .commands {
            // Able to get the state to the commands area
            CommandDelegate(compiler: compiler)
        }

        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}
```

**The following also doesn't quite work, but the behaviour of the document state is correct. The keybindings can't really be implemented this way:**

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct QCCApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: QCCDocument()) { file in
            // I implemented an initialiser instead of the `.attachDocument` method
            let compiler = UIStateController(targetting: file)
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(compiler)
        }
        .commands {
            // I can't reach the `compiler` variable
            CommandDelegate(compiler: /* compiler */)
        }

        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have the keybindings specific to one app instance/scene/window? If so, how does one implement such a thing? In the first example, pressing a keybind would affect both windows (and the same goes for other state).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935505/switfui-access-the-specific-scenes-viewmodel-on-macos/65959172#65959172

Comment: I could perhaps implement the second example I gave and push it into a global state array, so the commands have access to it, like your answer also gives. How's the memory usage if you open and close a lot of scenes without quitting the app?

Comment: I haven't tried it in any practical manner myself. I was just a challenge when the topic came up. There has to be a better way in document group since windows would likely be document specific but I don't use it right now.

Comment: Maybe a proposal should be filed for a `@SceneStateObject` in SwiftUI :)

Comment: That is a good idea. StateObject is advertised as being scene specific and it works but only if you put it in the ContentView and below. It has to the a WindowGroupStateObject / DocumentGroupStateObject / AppSceneStateObject.

Comment: Totally agree. `@StateObject` is scene specific, only if it's in that one particular scene. A global, per-scene property wrapper would probably fix all the problems

Comment: Coming back to this, I have noticed that my latter workaround also doesn't behave right. The `compiler` variable gets initialised every render, and I have an alert publisher inside of it, which means after modifying the initial state the notification would never show up.